# echo info from a database as a link

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to echo info from a database as a link, I tried the code below but got a parse error. is there some other way of doing it. Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("test") or die("Couldn't find database");
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo"<a href='home.php'> $info['firstname']</a>"
   }

      ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Missing semicolon

```
echo "<a href='home.php'>". $info['firstname']."</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting:" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\nest.php on line 9" error

Comment: @user1557515 in line 9 , the `echo` needs a `;` at the end, this answer has it..

Comment: Refresh the page and try again. I don't see any other error in the code that you provided

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<a href='home.php'> {$info['firstname']}</a>";
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much for that I forgot about curly parenthesis. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the semicolon from this line:

```
echo"<a href='home.php'> {$info['firstname']}</a>";
```

Comment: You need to surround the array with `{ }` otherwise it considers the $info as a variable rather than getting the value at index in the $info array.

Answer (score 1):

$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$fname = $info['firstname'];

?>

< a href='home.php'> < ?php echo $fname; ?> < /a>

i found this better much trick free

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the line ought to read:

```
echo"<a href='home.php'> $info[firstname]</a>";
```

Note the lack of quotes around `firstname`.